# Release "Carte E" to EU nationals

Tags: belgium

I'd like to ask a few questions about "Carte E"'s issuing, because I haven't understood that fully browsing in the internet.

I have been told that it is issued after 3 months for the first time and three paychecks are needed in order to get it issued, but on the internet I have read that proving to be a job seeker is enough, and not only that, but also that it is possible to get it delivered in oned day in "procédure d'urgence" by paying 140 euros or something like that.

Is it possible to get it issued in one day upon the first request of residence in Belgium, as long as I prove that I'm a job seeker?

These are the articles I've read, but I hope someone clarifies.

https://www.vivreenbelgique.be/sejour-en-belgique/droit-de-sejour-des-ressortissants-europeens

https://estinnes.be/accueil-3/reglements-taxes-2/reglements-communaux/delivrance-de-cartes-didentite-2/

http://www.ixelles.be/site/250-Document-attestant-de-la-permanence-du-sejour-carte-E+

Answer (score 2):

The first page linked in the question says "this site is no longer kept up to date."  It also contains several inaccurate statements that show that it is in fact out of date.

The second linked page is a list of fees associated with various forms of identification and residence documents.  It says nothing about the necessary conditions for making a successful application.

The third link concerns the *Carte E+,* which is not available before five years of residence in Belgium.  The link for *Carte E,* at least if you live in Ixelles, is
http://www.ixelles.be/site/686-Attestation-d-enregistrement-carte-E.

It is [not necessary to obtain such a card](https://www.belgium.be/en/family/residence_documents_for_belgium):

> For EU citizens, the  identity card or a passport is generally sufficient.

In some countries, the card is required if there is a non-EU family member who wishes to apply for a residence card under free movement law, but in Belgium, or at least in Brussels, this appears [not to be the case](https://www.brussels.be/relative-subject-eu-eea-or-switzerland).

It's a bit difficult to find information about relevant Belgian laws from national authorities because the corresponding pages of the Immigration Office are [under construction](https://dofi.ibz.be/fr/themes/citoyens-de-lunion).